# Do Harmonicas come in different keys?

Tags: harmonica

I am wondering if Harmonicas come in different keys. I have never played one and am confused about how they skip all the chromatic notes and stay in one key when they are playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonica#Diatonic Yes, harmonicas come in keys, but they also make chromatic harmonicas that will play in any key.  Of course, with flexibility comes complexity, so a chromatic harp takes some additional manipulation (a chromatic key) to make the notes.

Comment: Not only different keys, but also different scales.  I have a harmonic minor harmonica, for example.  (Which I more often play as if it's Major Phrygian.)

Answer (score 2):

When you blow, the harmonica produces the 1st, 3rd and 5th notes of a major scale. When you suck, you get the 2nd, 4th, 6th and 7th. You select precisely *which* note by narrowing your mouth aperture or by blocking unwanted notes with your tongue.

Blues players usually have several instruments in different keys. They often play the one in C when the blues is in G. The reason is that the one in G has an F# they don't need while the one in C has an F-natural they *do*. The rule is to use the one that's a fourth higher than the rest of the band.

Comment: Someone once said, '4th up for blues, same key for country'. Does that make sense to you? I've never played harp so I've no clue.

Comment: @Tetsujin: I hadn't heard that but yes, that's right. A useful reminder for a beginner or for a singer who's branching out! Drummers don't always need to be reminded "Pointy end away from you" but I tell 'em anyway.

Comment: I wondered why I keep dropping my sticks ;) As the joke goes, the difference between a drummer & a drum machine is you only have to punch information into a drum machine once. ;)

Comment: Heh heh! Looking at our passports, the customs guys used to ask, "Work or vacation?" "Work," we'd say. "Music." "How many musicians?" "Seven", we'd say. "And a drummer."

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like an interesting instrument. I will have to get one. I looked up some female harmonica players. I will have to listen to them.  http://www.harmonicalinks.com/women-harmonica-players.html#:~:text=Store%3A%201%20Lady%20A%202%20Louise%20Hoffsten%203,Vazquez%2010%20Jill%20%22Chilly%22%20Kurtz%20More%20items...%20

Comment: You're welcome. I can play tunes on one but I never did learn how to bend the notes properly, or how to impersonate a train.